# Reverting Replace in a text file

Tags: c#, replace, printing

I have a template I'm using to print labels, what I'm currently doing is a Replace() on the variable parts of my template and print it as is.
What is the best way to recover the original template after printing ? Revert manually all the changes ? Not modifying the template at first but create a copy that I modify, print and delete ?

The template looks like :

```
data1 : $1
data2 : $2
data3 : $3
data4 : $4
```

and then Replace() + print with :

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
text = text.Replace("$1", textBoxNumOF.Text);
text = text.Replace("$2", designation);
text = text.Replace("$3", textBoxNumOF.Text.Substring(textBoxNumOF.Text.Length - 4));
text = text.Replace("$4", "1");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, text, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
PrintDialog pd1 = new PrintDialog();
pd1.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
EnvoiImpression.SendFileToPrinter(@"Datamax-O'Neil H-4310 (Copie 1)", filePath);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your template and write the output which you are sending to the printer into a temp file inside the temp directory of windows.

Please see the following function:

```
        public static string GetTempFile()
        {
            // get temporary path
            var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();

            // get temporary filename
            string tempFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            //combine 
            return Path.Combine(tempPath, tempFileName);
        }
```

This way you do not need to revert your template and comply with the rules for temporary files on Windows. I suggest that you remember the files for deleting all your temporary files again from disk after your program / method was successful.

The function

```
EnvoiImpression.SendFileToPrinter(@"Datamax-O'Neil H-4310 (Copie 1)", filePath);
```

is sadly unknown to my. But perhaps there is also an overload which does accept a Stream? If so, you could edit your template in a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and do not even need to write to the disk.

Comment: I'll try that right away, thank you. The function you mentioned was found [here](https://github.com/andyyou/SendToPrinter/blob/master/Printer/RawPrinterHelper.cs) and used in an older project a coworker made, he sent me a link to it.